# Chutzpah nuget package - how to use it with VS2015 javascript file-what is the procedure

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, chutzpah

I a web app developed in asp.net, angularjs, typescript and a unit test project in Visual Studio solution. i have written the unit test for my javascript files, I read about chutzpah, i learned that it could be used to run the unit test in visual studio itself, I tried using the extension mention at https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe and https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71a4e9bd-f660-448f-bd92-f5a65d39b7f0 with these it runs fine on my local machine.

but now i want to integrate my unit test cases with visual studio (tfs) build process, and i found some info here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah/ regarding this. i cannot update my build controller just like that but at the end of this artical someone mention that there is nuget package that can be used. i uninstalled my old extension and tried to use the nuget package but now i dont see the context menu for chutzpah and also unit test is not shown in visual studio..

1. Will the nuget package gives same feature as extension, like running the test cases in visual studio itself, running single test case, also debugging the test case.
2. my unit test project is different so my test files doesn't go _publishWebSite folder, i can copy it to some folder, but is it compulsory to have it in _publishWebSite folder.

using nuget package looks easy on build machine. what it the complete and correct procedure

Answer (score 0):

The nuget package is really only useful if you want to automate your tests in the build from a CI server or the command line. It is also a good way to debug your tests. For VS integration you need to install the VSIX's from the Visual Studio gallery.